# How to test SSM getParameter method in jasmine?

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, unit-testing, jasmine

How do I test something like this?

```
const ssmParameterData = await ssm.getParameter(params, async (error, data) => {
if (error) throw error;

return data;
}).promise();
```

I have tried just mocking the method

```
spyOn(ssm, 'getParameter').and.returnValue(ssmParams);
```

and I get error like

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'promise' of undefined
```

Comment: use LocalStack https://github.com/localstack/localstack

Comment: Do you use `aws-sdk-js` module?

Comment: No, I have already refactored code and tested it with stub() method. Something like that:

`spyOn(ssm, 'getParameter').and.stub().and.returnValue({..});`

 Thank you for your comment

Answer (score 0):

Here is the unit test solution:

`index.js`:

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const ssm = new AWS.SSM();

async function main(params) {
  const ssmParameterData = await ssm
    .getParameter(params, (error, data) => {
      if (error) throw error;
      return data;
    })
    .promise();
  return ssmParameterData;
}

module.exports = { ssm, main };
```

`index.test.js`:

```js
const { ssm, main } = require('./');

describe('60138152', () => {
  it('should pass', async () => {
    const data = 'fake data';
    const getParameterRequestStub = { promise: jasmine.createSpy('promise') };
    const getParameterStub = spyOn(ssm, 'getParameter').and.callFake((params, callback) => {
      callback(null, data);
      getParameterRequestStub.promise.and.resolveTo(data);
      return getParameterRequestStub;
    });
    await expectAsync(main('test params')).toBeResolvedTo('fake data');
    expect(getParameterStub).toHaveBeenCalledWith('test params', jasmine.any(Function));
    expect(getParameterRequestStub.promise).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });

  it('should throw error', async () => {
    const mError = new Error('network');
    const getParameterRequestStub = { promise: jasmine.createSpy('promise') };
    const getParameterStub = spyOn(ssm, 'getParameter').and.callFake((params, callback) => {
      callback(mError);
      getParameterRequestStub.promise.and.rejectWith(mError);
      return getParameterRequestStub;
    });
    await expectAsync(main('test params')).toBeRejectedWithError('network');
    expect(getParameterStub).toHaveBeenCalledWith('test params', jasmine.any(Function));
  });
});
```

unit test results with 100% coverage:

```sh
Executing 2 defined specs...
Running in random order... (seed: 87758)

Test Suites & Specs:
(node:93291) ExperimentalWarning: The fs.promises API is experimental

1. 60138152
   ✔ should pass (10ms)
   ✔ should throw error (1ms)

>> Done!


Summary:

  Passed
Suites:  1 of 1
Specs:   2 of 2
Expects: 5 (0 failures)
Finished in 0.034 seconds

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.js |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```

source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jasmine-examples/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/60138152